# How to combine Box2dWeb and RequireJs together

Tags: backbone.js, box2d, requirejs

I built file structure for javascript game using RequireJs and Backbone. Now I have problem to combine it with Box2DWeb.

```
// Filename: game/controller/arena.js
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    '_69_',
    'game/controller/object',
    'game/model/arena',
    'game/view/arena',
    'box2d'
    ], function($, _, Backbone, _69_, Object, Model, View, Box2D){
        var ArenaController = Object.extend ({
            init : function (){
                this._super(Model, View);
                this.world = new b2World(
                    new b2Vec2(0, 10)    //gravity
                    ,  true                 //allow sleep
                    );
                this.appView;
                this.loops=0;
            },
            start : function (){
                _69_.l('start')
            },
            update :function (){
                _69_.l('update')
            },
            stop : function (){
                _69_.l('stop')
            }
        });

        return new ArenaController;
    });
```

But in console I get that b2World is not defined. What i should do to get it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know box2d but box2world does indeed not exist in that context unless it is a global object.

I presume here that you will need its namespace, if it is included in the box2d reference you defined in the required.js dependencies you might use

```
new Box2D.b2World(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try to including "box2D" in the require of your main.js file. Box2D will load as a global object which you can use later.

```
require([
  'app',
  'box2d'
], function(app){
     app.init();
});
```

You shouldn't mention it in the function or you could list it as "ignore":

```
require([
  'app',
  'box2d'
], function(app, ignore){
     app.init();

});
```

In the Chrome console, you could type Box2D and you should see it pop up as a global object. Once you know its global, you can start using it.

Then in your ArenaController you can list "box2d" in the define array but not in the function:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    '_69_',
    'game/controller/object',
    'game/model/arena',
    'game/view/arena',
    'box2d'
    ], function($, _, Backbone, _69_, Object, Model, View) {
         var ArenaController = Object.extend ({
            init : function (){
                this._super(Model, View);
                var b2World = Box2D.Dynamics.b2World; //Box2D should be available as a global
                this.world = new b2World(
                    new b2Vec2(0, 10)    //gravity
                    ,  true                 //allow sleep
                    );
                this.appView;
            }
        });

        return new ArenaController;
    });
```